# Simple SQL Questions with join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have some problems with join tables:

```
Table A -> ID,Col1,Col2,Col3

Table B -> Rank , ColX ,  A_ID (Relationship with A.ID)
```

I want to take higher Rank (each `A_ID` , like group by `A_ID`) of B table

my results must be something like `A.ID , Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , ""ColX""` , how can i do that ?

and i want my result count equals to A.ID count.

---

**TableA**

```
+--------------------+
| ID|Col1|Col2|Col3| |
+--------------------+
| 1 | C1 | C2 | C3   |
| 2 | C1 | C2 | C3   |
+--------------------+
```

**TABLE_B**

```
+-----------------------------+
| ID| COL_X     |RANK  |A_ID| |
+-----------------------------+
| 1 | SomeValue | 1    | 1    |
| 2 | some22222 | 2    | 1    |
| 3 | SOMEXXXX  | 3    | 1    |
| 4 | SOMEVAL   | 1    | 2    |
| 5 | VALUE     | 2    | 2    |
+-----------------------------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID| Col1| Col2 | Col3| COLX                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | C1  | C2   | C3  | SOMEXXXX (Higher Rank of TableB-> A_ID = 1) |
| 2 | C1  | C2   | C3  | VALUE (Higher Rank of TableB-> A_ID = 2)    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried?

Comment: i'm trying the answers solutions but i didnt solve it yet..

Comment: Actually my main problem is bigger than i wrote.. i work with 7-8 tables using left join , but i take exception that ,

----

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Panel_Product_Get, Line 99
Column 'Images.Url' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do this using a `subquery` by first finding the `max` for each `A_ID` and then joining to tableA and TableB to get your desired rows:

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.col1,
       a.Col2,
       a.Col3,
       b1.Col_X
FROM (
    SELECT a_id
        ,max(rank) AS MaxRank
    FROM tableb
    GROUP BY a_id
    ) b
INNER JOIN tablea a ON a.id = b.a_id
INNER JOIN tableb b1 ON b.a_id = b1.a_id AND b1.rank = b.MaxRank
ORDER BY a.ID;
```

[<kbd>SQL Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3f22/7/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to take the max rank from your table b for each row in table a?
There's lots of different ways of approaching this.  Here's one simple one:

```
with maxCTE as

    (select
     a_id,
     max(rank) as MaxRank
     from
     tableb
     group by 
     a_id
     )


         select
         *
         from
         tablea a
         inner join tableb b
         on a.id = b.a_id
         inner join maxcte c
         on b.a_id = c.a_id
         and b.rank = c.MaxRank
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3f22/2)

Basically, the CTE identifies the max rank for each a_id, then we join that back to tableb to get the details about that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as 
(select a_id, max(rank) as mxrnk
 from tableB 
 group by a_id)
select a.id, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col_x
from tableA a join x
on a.id = x.a_id
join tableB b
on x.mxrnk = b.rank
```

You can select max rank per a_id in the cte and use it to select the corresponding columns.

Comment: Actually, this is a better way. I don't know why I didn't use a CTE. I would suggest that you start with a semicolon as it's best practice.

Answer (score 0):

One is to INNER JOIN Table B onto Table A by ID's. You will have 3 records returned from Table B. If you ORDER those records by the COLX

```
SELECT
  ,a.ID
  ,a.Col1
  ,a.Col2
  ,a.Col3
  ,b.COLX
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS b on b.A_ID = a.id
ORDER BY b.COLX DESC
```

Then another way is joining a sub query of Table B that also has a sub query that filters Table B records to only the records with the highest RANK.

That way you can bring in COLX values from the highest RANK records from Table B that match the records of Table A.

I think at least...

```
SELECT
   a.ID
  ,a.Col1
  ,a.Col2
  ,a.Col3
  ,b.COLX
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT
                a.A_ID
               ,a.RANK
               ,a.COLX
             FROM TABLE_B a
             INNER JOIN (
                          SELECT
                             A_ID, 
                            ,MAX(RANK) AS [RANK] -- Highest Rank
                          FROM TABLE_B 
                          GROUP BY A_ID
                         ) AS b ON b.A_ID = a.A_ID AND b.RANK = a.RANK
            ) AS b on b.A_ID = a.id
ORDER BY a.ID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select A.*,D.Col_X    
     from 
          (Select C.COL_X,B.A_ID    
           from
                (Select A_ID,MAX(rank) as MAX_rank
                 from TABLE_B
                 group by A_ID) B ----- gets the highest rank and ID of the highest rank
            inner join  TABLE_B c 
             on 
           concat(C.A_ID,C.RANK)= concat(B.A_ID,B.MAX_rank)) D ---- Gets the highest rank name       
    inner join TABLE_A A 
    on D.A_ID=A.ID
```

OUTPUT:

ID  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col_X

1   c1      c2      c3     SOMEXXXX

2   c1      c2      c3     VALUE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please don't post code-only answers.